# Kick command with Discord.py not working for me

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make a discord moderation bot and I'm having trouble with the kick command.

For now, my code responds to **!kick @User** and **!kick @User [reason]**. And also if a member does not have the permissions.

But my problem is that I want it to respond if I put only **!kick** without any member.
According to something I read, it's because I'm not passing arguments, but I want it to return something if no arguments are passed. I don't know if I need conditions or exceptions to do it.

I tried doing *member not in ctx.message.content* but it doesn't work.

I already tried watching videos on the internet and reading some forums but I did not find a solution to my particular problem. This is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member = discord.Member, *,  reason = 'No reason'):
    
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.kick_members  == True:
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f'**{member}** was kicked.\nReason: _{reason}_')

    elif ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.kick_members  == False:
        await ctx.channel.send('You do not have permissions to do that.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an error message instead of an `if` statement. There is also a better way of checking if the user attempting to execute the command has required permissions.

You will have to import these for my method to work:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
```

Here's an example:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member = discord.Member, *,  reason = 'No reason'):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'**{member}** was kicked.\nReason: _{reason}_')

@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Please specify a member to kick.')
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('You do not have permissions to do that.')
```

If I missed anything/forgot something/misunderstood your question, please tell me.

Reference:

[commands.MissingRequiredArgument](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=missingpermissions#discord.ext.commands.MissingRequiredArgument)

[discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member)

[discord.py API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)